# Improvising Code Into A More DRY Approach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, function, sorting

I am formatting an array in the function *inputCategories*, and am unable to correctly add a third argument of "category" - forcing me replicate the function multiple times.

**Here is the current state:**

Calling the function with arguments.

```
$scope.categories = inputCategories($scope.item.categories, $scope.settings.categories);

function inputCategories (input, settings) {
    var updatedSettings = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(obj) {
        updatedSettings.push({"category": obj, "ticked": true});
    });
    var list = updatedSettings.concat(settings);
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a.category > b.category) - (a.category < b.category);
    });
    for ( var i = 1; i < list.length; i++ ){
        if(list[i-1].category == list[i].category) {
            list.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    return list;
};
```

**Here are the places which would require a third argument of "category".**

```
function inputCategories (input, settings) {
    var updatedSettings = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(obj) {
        updatedSettings.push({****"category"****: obj, "ticked": true});
    });
    var list = updatedSettings.concat(settings);
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a.****category**** > b.****category****) - (a.****category**** < b.****category****);
    });
    for ( var i = 1; i < list.length; i++ ){
        if(list[i-1].****category**** == list[i].****category****) {
            list.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    return list;
};
```

I think that the issue I am having is because I am mixing up strings and a variable that is a string, inside of the object on the fourth line...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
function inputCategories (input, settings, category) {
    var updatedSettings = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(obj) {
        var setting = { "ticked": true };
        setting[category] = obj;
        updatedSettings.push(setting);
    });
    var list = updatedSettings.concat(settings);
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a[category] > b[category]) - (a[category] < b[category]);
    });
    for ( var i = 1; i < list.length; i++ ){
        if(list[i-1][category] == list[i][category]) {
            list.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    return list;
};
```

Comment: That is perfect. Officially schooled... Thank you @Exo